# Set focus on input field for next element of certain class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set focus on the first input field in an element with class of .search-options that comes next one the page.

This is what I am using, however its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-search-options').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('.search-options *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to this: [jQuery: Find next element that is not a sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035206/jquery-find-next-element-that-is-not-a-sibling), except that the current element doesn't match the selector you are looking for. In that case you simply have to add it to the selection:

```
// Outside the event handler:
var $elements = $('.search-options *:input[type!=hidden]');

// Inside the event handler:
var $elementsWithCurrentElement = $elements.add(this);
$elementsWithCurrentElement.eq($elementsWithCurrentElement.index(this) + 1).focus();
```

---

If the element you are looking for is actually a sibling, have a look at [Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4933236/218196) .

Comment: There must be a cleaner way of doing this with $(this).next

Comment: Well, that's simply not what `.next` is there for: *"Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."* https://api.jquery.com/next/ . I.e. `$(this).next(...)` returns the next sibling *if and only if* the selector matches, otherwise an empty set. `.next` and `.nextAll` only work on the *siblings* of the selected element(s), not *all* following elements. I suggest to have a look at the examples in the documentation to get a better idea of how they work.

Comment: That's nice to know. Thanks for your help, I will go with it as it does what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the need for the colon in front of "input". This worked just fine for me:

```
$('#test input[type!="hidden"]:first')
```

But as an alternate solution, why not grab the first in the array of matches?

```
var inputs = $('#test input[type!="hidden"]');
if(inputs.length > 0) { $(inputs[0]).focus(); }
```